# Accidentally installed postgres10 and postgres12 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 came preinstalled with postgres10. Roughly 2 years ago I did a `sudo apt-get install postgresql` which must have installed postgres12. I never noticed that when I `sudo -u postgres psql` (where I have created all my databases over the past 2 years) it uses psql12, but connects to server version 10.

pg_lsclusters shows me that postgres10 listens on the default port 5432 and postgres12 listens on 5433. The status for both of them is "online".

**Questions**

1. When I do `sudo service postgresql status` I'm wondering which postgres service I'm actually looking at? And how can I configure which one should be targeted by "sudo service"?
2. How can I make psql point to postgres12 instead of postgres10?

Comment: Consider asking at -- https://askubuntu.com/ (a sister site to this one).

Comment: Why not upgrsde your cluster frpm 10 to 12 (or later;) and purge 10.  To confirm postgresql status is monitoring the cluster on port 5432 , why not stop the cluster on 5433 and check what the status says?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psql --port 5433`. Or if this port setting is too frequent, `export PGPORT=5433`.

Typical network services are launch here: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`. Perhaps you will find both Postgres launch services, and you can analyse how Postgres server are launched. But since I don’t know how you manage to install 2 independent Postgres servers (usually, installing a recent server replaces the previous one), I can’t help more.